# User running a scheduled job in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to force all scheduled job runs to be performed by a certain user, instead of the user which enabled the scheduling?

What I meant is the rundeck user, not the node user, like those defined in the realm.properties file.

Let's say I have 2 users defined: user1 and user2.
user1 logs into rundeck and starts a job. In the recent executions list the job will appear as performed "by user1".

user1 now edits the job and enables the "Schedule to run repeatedly" option.
When the job starts on the schedule it will also be reported as ran "by user1".

What I need is a way to tell rundeck that all jobs which have "Schedule to run repeatedly" enabled should be run by another user (such as user2) instead of the user that edited them and enabled the scheduling (user1).

Why do I want this? Two reasons:

**1. Cleanliness:** I want all automated jobs to be listed as ran by a "rundeck service" user.

**2. Issues with LDAP and ACLs:** our rundeck users are imported from LDAP and rundeck ACLs are set for LDAP groups. When a job is run on schedule rundeck will not call the LDAP server to retrieve the group list, the user will then be treated as having no group and consequently no ACL and the job will fail because of lack of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a different account via the `username` attribute for that Node definition.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the rundeck user, not the ssh user on nodes. I edited the question to make it clearer.